# Shell script get the right PID

Tags: linux, shell, pid, init.d

I wrote a little program that I want to start as a service on Opensuse 11.3
This is from the init.d script, it starts my processes as I want but I don't get the right PID.

What am I missing?

```
echo "Starting DHCPALERT"
for (( i = 1; i <= $DHCP_AL_DAEMONS; i++ ))
do
    var="DHCP_AL_$i"
    START_CMD="exec /sbin/startproc -p "$DHCP_AL_PID_DIR"p_"$i".pid -l "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"log_"$i".log "$DHCPALERT_BIN" "${!var}" &"
    eval $START_CMD
    echo "PID: "$!
    echo "Command: "$START_CMD
done
```

results in

```
PID: 47347
Command: (/sbin/startproc -p /var/log/sthserver/dhcpalert/p_2.pid -l /var/log/sthserver/dhcpalert/log_2.log /usr/sbin/dhcpalert -i eth1 -c ./test.sh -a 00:15:5D:0A:16:07 -v )&
```

but pidof returns some othe pid.

If I try to execute it directly:

```
exec /sbin/startproc -p "$DHCP_AL_PID_DIR"p_"$i".pid -l "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"log_"$i".log "$DHCPALERT_BIN" "${!var}" &
```

Then I get errors:

```
startproc:  exit status of parent of /usr/sbin/dhcpalert: 1
```

I suppose because I don't escape the variables the right way?

This is the whole script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check for missing binaries (stale symlinks should not happen)
# Note: Special treatment of stop for LSB conformance
DHCPALERT_BIN=/usr/sbin/dhcpalert
#-x FILE exists and is executable
test -x $DHCPALERT_BIN || { echo "$DHCPALERT_BIN not installed"; 
    if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
    else exit 5; fi; }

# Check for existence of needed config file and read it
DHCPALERT_CONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/dhcpalert
#-r FILE exists and is readable
test -r $DHCPALERT_CONFIG || { echo "$DHCPALERT_CONFIG not existing";
    if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
    else exit 6; fi; }

# Read config to system VARs for this shell session only same as "source FILE"
. $DHCPALERT_CONFIG

#check for exitstence of the log dir
if [ -d "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR" ]; then
        echo "exists 1"
        echo "exists 2"
        echo "exists 3"
        if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
            echo "Deleting all old log files from: "
            echo "Dir:... "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR
            rm -R $DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR
            mkdir $DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR
        fi
    else
        echo "does not exist 1"
        echo "does not exist 2"
        echo "does not exist 3"
        echo "Directory for Logfiles does not exist."
        echo "Dir:... "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR
        echo "Createing dir..."
        mkdir $DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR
    fi


. /etc/rc.status

# Reset status of this service
rc_reset

case "$1" in
    start)
    echo "Starting DHCPALERT"
    for (( i = 1; i <= $DHCP_AL_DAEMONS; i++ ))
    do
        var="DHCP_AL_$i"

        exec /sbin/startproc -p "$DHCP_AL_PID_DIR"p_"$i".pid -l "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"log_"$i".log "$DHCPALERT_BIN" "${!var}" &

       # START_CMD="exec /sbin/startproc -p "$DHCP_AL_PID_DIR"p_"$i".pid -l "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"log_"$i".log "$DHCPALERT_BIN" "${!var}" &"
       # eval $START_CMD
        echo "PID: "$!
       # echo "Command: "$START_CMD
    done

    rc_status -v
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Shutting down DHCPALERT "

    /sbin/killproc -TERM $DHCPALERT_BIN
    rc_status -v
    ;;
    try-restart|condrestart)
    if test "$1" = "condrestart"; then
        echo "${attn} Use try-restart ${done}(LSB)${attn} rather than condrestart ${warn}(RH)${norm}"
    fi
    $0 status
    if test $? = 0; then
        $0 restart
    else
        rc_reset    # Not running is not a failure.
    fi
    rc_status
    ;;
    restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    rc_status
    ;;
    force-reload)
    echo -n "Reload service DHCPALERT "
    /sbin/killproc -HUP $DHCPALERT_BIN
    rc_status -v
    ;;
    reload)
    echo -n "Reload service DHCPALERT "
    /sbin/killproc -HUP $DHCPALERT_BIN
    rc_status -v
    ;;
    status)
    echo -n "Checking for service DHCPALERT "
    /sbin/checkproc $DHCPALERT_BIN
    rc_status -v
    ;;
    probe)

    test /etc/DHCPALERT/DHCPALERT.conf -nt /var/run/DHCPALERT.pid && echo reload
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|try-restart|restart|force-reload|reload|probe}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
rc_exit
```

The configfile:

```
## Specifiy where to store the Pid files
DHCP_AL_PID_DIR="/var/log/sthserver/dhcpalert/"
##
## Specifiy where to store the Log file
DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR="/var/log/sthserver/dhcpalert/"
##
## is needed to determine how many vars should be read and started!
DHCP_AL_DAEMONS="2"
##                        
## Then DHCP_AL_<number> to specify the command that one instance of 
## dhcpalert should be started
DHCP_AL_1="-i eth0 -c ./test.sh -a 00:15:5D:0A:16:06 -v"
DHCP_AL_2="-i eth1 -c ./test.sh -a 00:15:5D:0A:16:07 -v"
```

Comment: What sort of Linux are you using?  And what shell?

Comment: sorry thought I already wrote that. It's opensuse 11.3 and bash

Comment: Why do you use `eval` to start the command?

Comment: Because I had problems with escaping the variables right and after a google search this worked. How would I do it without?

Comment: Can you try it without `eval`? `/sbin/startproc -p "$DHCP_AL_PID_DIR"p_"$i".pid -l "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"log_"$i".log "$DHCPALERT_BIN" "${!var}" &`

Comment: without eval this is what is returned `pepi-vm:/etc/init.d # startproc:  exit status of parent of /usr/sbin/dhcpalert: 1
startproc:  exit status of parent of /usr/sbin/dhcpalert: 1`

Comment: @fridolin69 Can you show all parts of your script?

Comment: @konsolebox I added the script and the configfile. I used the skeleton script from Opensuse to start with.

Comment: Is it possible for the script to run as `#!/bin/bash` instead?

Comment: Did it but no changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `exec` to it to prevent forking:

```
START_CMD="(exec /sbin/startproc -p "$DHCP_AL_PID_DIR"p_"$i".pid -l "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"log_"$i".log "$DHCPALERT_BIN" "${!var}") &"
```

#### Update. Please try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check for missing binaries (stale symlinks should not happen)
# Note: Special treatment of stop for LSB conformance
DHCPALERT_BIN=/usr/sbin/dhcpalert
#-x FILE exists and is executable
[[ -x $DHCPALERT_BIN ]] || {
    echo "$DHCPALERT_BIN not installed"
    if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then
        exit 0
    else
        exit 5
    fi
}

# Check for existence of needed config file and read it
DHCPALERT_CONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/dhcpalert
#-r FILE exists and is readable
[[ -r $DHCPALERT_CONFIG ]] || {
    echo "$DHCPALERT_CONFIG not existing"
    if [[ $1 == stop ]]; then
        exit 0
    else
        exit 6
    fi
}

# Read config to system VARs for this shell session only same as "source FILE"
. "$DHCPALERT_CONFIG"

#check for exitstence of the log dir

CREATE_DIR=false

if [[ -d $DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR ]]; then
    echo "exists 1"
    echo "exists 2"
    echo "exists 3"
    if [[ $1 == start ]]; then
        echo "Deleting all old log files from: "
        echo "Dir:... $DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"
        rm -R "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"
        CREATE_DIR=true
    fi
else
    echo "does not exist 1"
    echo "does not exist 2"
    echo "does not exist 3"
    echo "Directory for Logfiles does not exist."
    CREATE_DIR=true
fi

if [[ $CREATE_DIR == true ]]; then
    echo "Dir:... $DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"
    echo "Createing dir..."
    mkdir "$DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR" || {
        echo "Failed to create directory $DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR"
        exit 1
    }
fi

. /etc/rc.status

# Reset status of this service
rc_reset

case "$1" in
start)
    echo "Starting DHCPALERT"
    for (( I = 1; I <= DHCP_AL_DAEMONS; ++I )); do
        REF="DHCP_AL_${I}[@]"
        COMMAND=(/sbin/startproc -p "${DHCP_AL_PID_DIR}p_${I}.pid" -l "${DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR}log_${I}.log" "$DHCPALERT_BIN" "${!REF}")
        echo "COMMAND: ${COMMAND[*]}"
        "${COMMAND[@]}" &
        PID=$!
        echo "PID: $PID"
    done
    rc_status -v
    ;;
stop)
    echo -n "Shutting down DHCPALERT "
    /sbin/killproc -TERM "$DHCPALERT_BIN"
    rc_status -v
    ;;
try-restart|condrestart)
    [[ $1 == condrestart ]] && echo "${attn} Use try-restart ${done}(LSB)${attn} rather than condrestart ${warn}(RH)${norm}"
    "$0" status  ## ??
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        "$0" restart
    else
        rc_reset    # Not running is not a failure.
    fi
    rc_status
    ;;
restart)
    "$0" stop
    "$0" start
    rc_status
    ;;
    force-reload)
    echo -n "Reload service DHCPALERT "
    /sbin/killproc -HUP "$DHCPALERT_BIN"
    rc_status -v
    ;;
reload)
    echo -n "Reload service DHCPALERT "
    /sbin/killproc -HUP "$DHCPALERT_BIN"
    rc_status -v
    ;;
status)
    echo -n "Checking for service DHCPALERT "
    /sbin/checkproc "$DHCPALERT_BIN"
    rc_status -v
    ;;
probe)
    [[ /etc/DHCPALERT/DHCPALERT.conf -nt /var/run/DHCPALERT.pid ]] & echo reload
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|try-restart|restart|force-reload|reload|probe}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

rc_exit
```

Config file:

```
## Specifiy where to store the Pid files
DHCP_AL_PID_DIR="/var/log/sthserver/dhcpalert/"
##
## Specifiy where to store the Log file
DHCP_AL_LOG_DIR="/var/log/sthserver/dhcpalert/"
##
## is needed to determine how many vars should be read and started!
DHCP_AL_DAEMONS="2"
##
## Then DHCP_AL_<number> to specify the command that one instance of
## dhcpalert should be started
DHCP_AL_1=(-i eth0 -c ./test.sh -a 00:15:5D:0A:16:06 -v)
DHCP_AL_2=(-i eth1 -c ./test.sh -a 00:15:5D:0A:16:07 -v)
```

Comment: still the wrong ones even if I remove the parentheses

Comment: tried it, thx but the pid file is not created by startproc, that would be something I have to do myself at least thats what I understood from reading the man page and stackoverflow. So the read command fails obviously.

Comment: @fridolin69 So `-p "${DHCP_AL_PID_DIR}p_${I}.pid"` is not really helpful?

Comment: Also, you create two instances of your `dhcpalert` application. How do you plan to manage both PIDs?

Comment: I think it works the way it should do. But doesn't create the file, this file is just to read from and if there is already a process with the pid and the name (dhcpalert) then no ! new process is beeing launched. But I don't understand how I should create this file since I have problems to find out the right pid.
This becomes handy if one tries to start it twice but I gues this can be handled with an if [already running] then...

Comment: But I have an other issue with the log files. They are created but stay empty although I print something out in the first line of the dhcpalert-program, any ideas on this?

Comment: I planned to manage the instances with different pid files.
I have to admitt that I have a hard time understanding what exacly you have written here.
`REF="DHCP_AL_${I}[@]"` why do I need the `[@]` here? isn't @ a reference to all parameters passed to the script?

Comment: @fridolin69 To prevent using `eval` I decided to store your arguments as arrays. See how they are now stored in your configuration file. The reference is a form of indirect variable expansion as if it makes you do `"${DHCP_AL_1[@]}"`.

Comment: Anyway I still don't read much how things work but going back to our main problem, can you try reading `$!` again? `"${COMMAND[@]}"` works already well right? I made the update for it.

Comment: It prints out the wrong pids, it prints 6550 and the actual process has 6552 but the numbers were always close.

Comment: @fridolin69 I think what you really want to use is `start_daemon` and not `startproc`. According to documentation: 
       The  start_daemon  does  not  support  the  options  -(t|T) <sec>   nor
       -(w|W <file list>)  for waiting for success and the option -s for a new
       session as this variant does not fork to start the executable.

Comment: `start_daemon` is a symlink to `startproc` on this system

Comment: @fridolin69 Just try it. Perhaps the binary behaves differently if called as `start_daemon`.

Comment: wooooooow but how could that be? I don't get it. I executed it twice and the PIDs were correct :). Do you have any idea why the logfiles stay empty? And why do i need the parenthesies in the configfile?

Comment: It's just similar to bash working in POSIX mode when called as `sh`. You'd noticed `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/bash`. The difference with `start_daemon` over `startproc` is that `start_daemon` doesn't do forking so the pid it has becomes the pid of the process that it summons. In the config file, you store the arguments as arrays to keep them well formed even with spaces. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html.

Comment: I'm not sure why they're empty. Do they show messages with `startproc`?

Comment: Well I thought I can't or shouldn't create arrays in the config file.But anyway if it works why not...  how do I read the `[*] and [@]` ? can't find anything this. I mean what I found is that the @ symbol is a reference to all passed parameters but why does this have to be appended when the command is concatenated a line before?

The logfiles are empty with both commands except if i pass it a wrong interface and there are errors printed. But then a short message from the program start that is always printed is also there.

Comment: @fridolin69 I suggest reading a tutorial about arrays: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/. And your best reference when it comes to bash script is `man bash` and `help`. The online version is also much readable: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/. `"${x[@]}"` expands to multiple arguments while `"${x[*]}"` only expands as a single string where every element is separated by the first value in `IFS`.

Comment: If some messages are shown on the log files then at least we can say that `start_daemon` redirects the output to it well.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a shell-command inside parentheses you start a new sub-shell. You run this sub-shell in the background and it's that sub-shells process id you get with `$!`.

There are two solutions: The first is to not run the `/sbin/startproc` command in a subshell, but directly and put that in the background. The secomd solution is to monitor the pid file created by `/sbin/startproc`.